# JavaDoc link sub items of link

Tags: java, javadoc

Is there a way to write a JavaDoc like in the following example?

```
{@link MyObject#getItem()#getSubItem()}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct implementation for that scenario would be the @see.

Comment: With @see, I have the same issue